# When I will click on register button it should redirect me to next page but that's not happening

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

So,basically when I will click on register button it should redirect me to next page.I tried out various ways but that not worked.Even there are no error,still whenever I click on button it is clicked but is not directed to next page.I have pasted all the code below.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

this is my new_user_login.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    tools:context=".NewUserActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="106dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="581dp"
        android:text="   REGISTRATION "
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="487dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="530dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="440dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_mail"
        android:text="EMAIL ID"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="388dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="186dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="351dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_phone"
        android:text="PHONE NO."
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="306dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="135dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="254dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_username"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usname"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="205dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="131dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_password"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passsword"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="113dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="324dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:background="@color/DeepPink"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:onClick="registration"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="24dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is NewUserACtivity.java file

```
    package com.example.moviebookingapp2;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class NewUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        EditText name;
        EditText email;
        EditText phone;
        EditText usname;
        EditText passsword;
        Button register;
        ToastManager toastManager;
    
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.new_user_login);
    
    
    
            name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
            usname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usname);
            passsword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passsword);
            register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    
    
            register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String NAME = name.getText().toString().trim();
                    String EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String PHONENO = phone.getText().toString().trim();
                    String username = usname.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password = passsword.getText().toString().trim();
                    String emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]{3,32}+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,32}+$";
                    String phonePattern = "(0/91)?[7-9][0-9]{9}";
    
    
                    boolean isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty = !NAME.isEmpty()
                            || !EMAIL.isEmpty()
                            || !PHONENO.isEmpty()
                            || !username.isEmpty()
                            || !password.isEmpty();
    
    
                    ToastManager toastManager = new ToastManager(NewUserActivity.this);
    
                    if (isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty) {
                        // NAME VALIDATION
                        if (NAME.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER NAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((NAME.length() > 3) && (NAME.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("NAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 3-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!NAME.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ONLY ALPHABETS ALLOWED", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                        //EMAIL VALIDATION
                        if (EMAIL.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER EMAIL-ID", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!(EMAIL.matches(emailPattern))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("INVALID EMAIL", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                       //PHONE NUMBER VALIDATION
                        if (PHONENO.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!(PHONENO.length() == 10)) {
                            toastManager.addToast("INVALID PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!(PHONENO.matches(phonePattern))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("INVALID PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                        //USERNAME VALIDATION
                        if (username.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER USERNAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                        //PASSWORD VALIDATION
                        if (password.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER PASSWORD", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastManager.addToast("ALL FIELDS ARE COMPULSORY", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
    
                   // Finally show all toast all screen
                    toastManager.show();
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
    
        }
    
        public void registration(View view) {
            register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent p = new Intent(NewUserActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(p);
                }
            });
        }
    }

this is the page that shoild open when i will click that register button.
this is my MAinActivity2.java code

package com.example.moviebookingapp2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements ClickedListener {
    RecyclerView recycleview1;
    List<String> titles;
    List<Integer>images;
    GridAdapter adapter;
    Button register;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intropage);


        recycleview1 = findViewById(R.id.recycleview1);

        titles = new ArrayList<>();
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        titles.add("LATEST MOVIES");
        titles.add("UPCOMING MOVIES");
        titles.add("TRENDING MOVIES");
        titles.add("NOW PLAYING");
        titles.add("RELEASED MOVIES");
        titles.add("HINDI MOVIES");
        titles.add("MARATHI MOVIES");
        titles.add("ENGLISH MOVIES");
        titles.add("TELUGU MOVIES");
        titles.add("TAMIL MOVIES");


        images.add(R.drawable.latestmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.upcomingmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.trendingmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.nowplaying);
        images.add(R.drawable.releasedmovie);
        images.add(R.drawable.hindimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.marathimovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.englishmovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.telugumovies);
        images.add(R.drawable.tamilmovies);


        adapter =  new GridAdapter(this,titles,images,this);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recycleview1.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recycleview1.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void onPictureClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

Comment: why you need to have two  `register.setOnClickListener` ?

Comment: Remove `android:onClick="registration"` as you already have on click listener

Comment: Okay I wll try that

Comment: Still the intent is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having 2 setOnClickListener to your register, try to remove one of them like so :

```
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String NAME = name.getText().toString().trim();
                    String EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String PHONENO = phone.getText().toString().trim();
                    String username = usname.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password = passsword.getText().toString().trim();
                    String emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]{3,32}+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,32}+$";
                    String phonePattern = "(0/91)?[7-9][0-9]{9}";
    
    
                    boolean isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty = !NAME.isEmpty()
                            || !EMAIL.isEmpty()
                            || !PHONENO.isEmpty()
                            || !username.isEmpty()
                            || !password.isEmpty();
    
    
                    ToastManager toastManager = new ToastManager(NewUserActivity.this);
    
                    if (isAtLeastOneEditTextNotEmpty) {
                        // NAME VALIDATION
                        if (NAME.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER NAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((NAME.length() > 3) && (NAME.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("NAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 3-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!NAME.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ONLY ALPHABETS ALLOWED", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                        //EMAIL VALIDATION
                        if (EMAIL.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER EMAIL-ID", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!(EMAIL.matches(emailPattern))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("INVALID EMAIL", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                       //PHONE NUMBER VALIDATION
                        if (PHONENO.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!(PHONENO.length() == 10)) {
                            toastManager.addToast("INVALID PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!(PHONENO.matches(phonePattern))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("INVALID PHONE NO.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                        //USERNAME VALIDATION
                        if (username.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER USERNAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
    
                        //PASSWORD VALIDATION
                        if (password.isEmpty()) {
                            toastManager.addToast("ENTER PASSWORD", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                            toastManager.addToast("PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    } else {
                        toastManager.addToast("ALL FIELDS ARE COMPULSORY", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
    
                   // Finally show all toast all screen
                    toastManager.show();
                    Intent p = new Intent(NewUserActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(p);
                }
            });
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
    
        }
```

Comment: Excatly,Now my page is getting intended,but the validations are not working,like if I will not fill any data ...it should validate me until i fill all of them.....but intead its showing me the toast msg and directing me to next page without filling any data

Comment: You can use if statement to check all the required fields. If they aren't empty, intent should be called. Else call the toast msg.

Comment: Yes I have used that still its not working bro

Comment: Can u be more clear ......I am new to this .....And I am totally confused

Comment: Can you post another question about that?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the registration() method only sets the onClickListener, it doesn't call it.

It seems like you don't set the onclicklistener and even if you did the second one (which creates toasts) might override it.

So either call registration() instead of the other one or call registration inside of the other onClickListener, without the onClick stuff (because the code is supposed to be executed, no onClick required if you are inside of the listener)

Comment: Okay so I removed My one method....But still the intent is not working